# How to assign On Page Property on another page in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties

I have a page with name Default.aspx, on **Default.aspx** I have Property

```
 protected string pageNo = string.Empty;
 public string PageNo
        {
            get { return pageNo; }
            set { pageNo = value; }
        }
```

and second page is **myPage.aspx** have the similar property.
Now I want to access the Default.aspx page property on the myPage.aspx or assign it in the myPage.aspx page's property.
Is it possible if yes then how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing cross page posting. you can use page.PreviousPage. It needs from asp.net 3.5 or after.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. By the time MyPage.aspx is executing, Default.aspx has been garbage collected. Your options are Session variables, Url parameters, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx):

Example usage in article:

[HttpContext.Items - a Per-Request Cache Store](https://web.archive.org/web/20210608183011/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx)